# Python nltk counting word and phrase frequency

Tags: python, nltk, word-frequency

I am using NLTK and trying to get the word phrase count up to a certain length for a particular document as well as the frequency of each phrase. I tokenize the string to get the data list.

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.collocations import *


data = ["this", "is", "not", "a", "test", "this", "is", "real", "not", "a", "test", "this", "is", "this", "is", "real", "not", "a", "test"]

bigrams = ngrams(data, 2)

bigrams_c = {}
for b in bigrams:
    if b not in bigrams_c:
        bigrams_c[b] = 1
    else:
        bigrams_c[b] += 1
```

the above code gives and output like this:

```
(('is', 'this'), 1)
(('test', 'this'), 2)
(('a', 'test'), 3)
(('this', 'is'), 4)
(('is', 'not'), 1)
(('real', 'not'), 2)
(('is', 'real'), 2)
(('not', 'a'), 3)
```

which is partially what I am looking for.

My question is, is there a more convenient way to do this for say up to phrases that are 4 or 5 in length without duplicating this code only to change the count variable?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you tagged this `nltk`, here's how to do it using the `nltk`'s methods, which have some more features than the ones in the standard python collection.

```
from nltk import ngrams, FreqDist
all_counts = dict()
for size in 2, 3, 4, 5:
    all_counts[size] = FreqDist(ngrams(data, size))
```

Each element of the dictionary `all_counts` is a dictionary of ngram frequencies. For example, you can get the five most common trigrams like this:

```
all_counts[3].most_common(5)
```

Comment: holy smokes, this works so much better than what I previously wrote. Thank you very much, superb answer!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah don't run this loop, use `collections.Counter(bigrams)` or `pandas.Series(bigrams).value_counts()` to compute the counts in a one-liner.