# Most frequents words in Python

Tags: python

I was trying to implement a code that would allow me to find the 10 most frequent words in a text. I'm new at python, and am more used to languages like C#, java or even C++. Here is what I did:

```
f = open("bigtext.txt","r")

word_count = {}
```

Basicaly, my idea is to create a dictionary that contains the number of times that each word is present in my text. If the word is not present, I will add it to the dictionary with the value of 1. If the world is already present in the dictionary, I will increment its value by 1.

```
for x in f.read().split():
    if x not in word_count:
        word_count[x] = 1
    else:
        word_count[x] += 1

sorted(word_count.values)
```

Here, I will sort my dictionary by values (since I'm looking for the 10 most frequent worlds, I need the 10 words with the biggest values).

```
for keys,values in word_count.items():
    values = values + 1
    print(word_count[-values])
    if values == 10:
        break
```

Here is the part were it all fails. I know now for sure (since I sorted my dictionary by the value of the values). That my 10 most frequent words are the 10 last elements of my dictionary. I want to display those. So I decided to initialize `values at 1` and to display my dictionary backward till `values = 10` so that I won't need to display more than what I need. But unfortunately, I get this following error:

> ```
> File "<ipython-input-19-f5241b4c239c>", line 13
>     for keys,values in word_count.items()
>                                          ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

I do know that my mistake is that I didn't display my dictionary backwards correctly. But I don't know how to proceed elsewhere. So if someone can tell me how to properly display my last 10 elements in my dictionary, I would very much appreciate it. Thank You.

Comment: you forgot a colon `:` after `items()`

Comment: Take a look at [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). It will do the counting for you ;)

Comment: Dictionaries can’t be sorted. Your `sorted()` call will return a list of all the values (no keys) from the dictionary, but won’t do anything to the dictionary itself.

Comment: You're right I did forget the `:` after `items()` now the mistake is the following: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: I would recommend looking into [`nltk`](https://www.nltk.org/).  This will allow you to ignore common stopwords, etc.

Comment: I see Ben. Thank you for your remark. I can't sort a dictionary. Can you give me a more suitable data structure for my problem then please?

Comment: I recommend using Python NLTK library, take a look at the accepted response on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669141/python-nltk-counting-word-and-phrase-frequency . Nltk is much larger and will be of help to you in similar future tasks.

Comment: I'll second a comment re collections.Counter. It has built-in function exactly for the task, your entire code will fit in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn’t want to use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), you could do something like this:

```
for word, count in sorted(word_count.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1])[:10]:
    print(word, count)
```

This gets all the words in the dictionary, along with their counts, into a list of tuples; sorts that list by the 2nd item in each tuple (the count) descending, and then only prints the first (I.e. highest) ten of those.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just tried it and it works like a charm. Your solution is much more elegant than mine. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

I would like to address a big thank you to Ben who told me that I can't sort a dictionary like that.

So this is my final solution (hoping it would help someone else);

```
my_words = []

for keys, values in word_count.items():
    my_words.append((values,keys))
```

I created a list and I added to it the values I had in my dictionary with the following word for each value.

```
my_words.sort(reverse = True)
```

I then sorted my list according to the value in reverse (so that my 10 most frequent worlds would be the 10 first element of my list)

```
print("The 10 most frequent words in this text are:")
print()

for key, val in my_words[:10]:
    print (key, val)
```

I then simply displayed the 10 first elements of my list.

I would also like to thank all of you who told me about NLTK. I will try it later to have a more optimal and accurate solution.

Thank You so much for your help.